# Needing assist with using a PIVOT in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

In my T-SQL code the display of my result set appears as follows.  The RN is a ROW_NUMBER counter based on AgentNumber:

```
Period      AgentNumber LocationName    AgencyName  MarketingRep    RTR Quotes  RN
------      ----------- ------------    ----------  ------------    --- ------  --
Jan-20      123         Acme            Acme        csmith          4   0       1
Feb-20      123         Acme            Acme        csmith          8   50      2
Jan-20      456         ZZZ             ZZZ         bbaker          12  0       1
Feb-20      456         ZZZ             ZZZ         bbaker          85  5       2
```

I've been trying to google for some help but struggling with having multiple SUM columns using PIVOT. Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish in getting my result set to appear as follows:

```
                                                       Jan-20           Feb-20
AgentNumber LocationName    AgencyName  MarketingRep   RTR      Quotes  RTR     Quotes
----------- ------------    ----------  ------------   ---      ------  ---     ------
123         Acme            Acme        csmith         4        0       8       50
456         ZZZ             ZZZ         bbaker         12       0       85      5
```

Here is my T-SQL, I'm struggling with spanning the Period column to its own row and and above where the RTR column starts.

Here is my T-SQL code:

```
SELECT mde.[Period]
    , l.AgentNumber, l.LocationName, l.AgencyName, l.MarketingRep
    , mde.RealTimeRateQuotes
    , mde.Quotes
    , mde.RN
FROM #tempMonthlyDataElements mde
LEFT JOIN #tempUWIssues i
ON mde.AgentID = i.AgentSysID
AND mde.[Year] = i.[Year]
AND mde.[Period] = i.[Period]
AND mde.RN = i.RN
LEFT JOIN #tempPaperlessEFTPercentages pep
ON mde.AgentID = pep.AgentSysID
AND mde.[Year] = pep.[Year]
AND mde.[Period] = pep.[Period]
AND mde.RN = pep.RN
LEFT JOIN #tempAgentNewRenewalCommissionRates acr
ON mde.AgentID = acr.AgentSysID
LEFT JOIN #tempLocations l
ON mde.AgentID = l.AgentSysID 
LEFT JOIN #tempLastNoteInfo lni
ON l.LocationID = lni.LocationID
ORDER BY AgentSysID asc, mde.RN asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select mde.Period,
    l.AgentNumber, l.LocationName, l.AgencyName, l.MarketingRep,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mde.Period = 'Jan-20' THEN mde.RealTimeRateQuotes END) as jan_20_rtr,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mde.Period = 'Jan-20' THEN mde.Quotes             END) as jan_20_quote,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mde.Period = 'Jan-20' THEN mde.RealTimeRateQuotes END) as feb_20_rtr,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mde.Period = 'Jan-20' THEN mde.Quotes             END) as feb_20_quote
from ...
group by mde.Period
```

Note: are you really storing periods in this fomat? That should really be a `date` instead.

Comment: thanks for replying, unfortunately that is the format that the user is wanting. Is there not a way to do this using the PIVOT function?  Thanks.